# Calling a method of a @Singleton bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-8, ejb

In Java SE I used to call a singleton instance method this way:

```
MySingleton.getInstance().method();
```

Now, in Java EE 8 I have a @Singleton bean. How can I call a method? Do I have to inject the Singleton instance in the caller?

```
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MySingletonBean {

  @Lock(LockType.WRITE)
  public void method() {
    // .....
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to inject the Singleton instance in the caller?

Yes, that's the preferred approach.

Just do

```
@Inject
private MySingletonBean name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Singleton in JEE is kind of Session bean. It means, that you can inject it with @EJB annotation.

```
@EJB
private SingletonBean singleton;
```